# Is there a style / terminology guide for Android OS application documentation?

Tags: style, technical-writing, software-documentation, user-guides

This relates to my earlier question: [Habits and routines for my first tech writing job](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/5208/my-first-professional-writing-job-any-advice)

I will be involved with writing documentation for an Android OS business application. Is there an Android style guide for this kind of documentation? I really need to know the standard terminology for User Interface interactions.

Google doesn’t turn up anything. All I find are style guides for other OS’s (e.g. here’s the [Apple Publications Style Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/APStyleGuide/APSG_2009.pdf)) and the [Android User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) which, at first glance, doesn’t seem to have what I’m looking for.

Comment: Things like _swipe_, _tap_, and _pinch_?

Comment: That's right.  And do you say "Settings", "Options" or ... something else?  Is it the "screen" or the "display"?  What should I call that bar that's always at the top of the screen?

In the end, I solved my problem by downloading the Android User Manual and just copying the terminology (and style) from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but don't discount the [Android UI Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html) site immediately. While it isn't exactly overflowing with information, and it is specifically aimed at the text used **within** applications, the site does have a [Writing Style page](http://developer.android.com/design/style/writing.html).

6 rules, 5 examples. But perhaps the application style could do well translated to documentation?

Comment: Thanks! I missed that and, yes, it's helpful. Next time somebody tells me that their stuffy corporate jargon looks more "professional" I can point them to this style-guide.